# VB6 permission denied when adding value to password input

Tags: vb6, permission-denied

Found answer to issue - must use web.Document.getElementById("password").Value = strOldPassword

I have a VB6 application that is supposed to log in to a website. It worked at one time but hasn't been run in years and now needs to be updated. I can get the username from the database and insert into the username input on the website fine, but when I get to password I get "Permission Denied" error. I assume it has to do with password fields. Anybody have a way around that?

The VB6 code that is giving me the error:

```
MsgBox ("need to enter password") ' This alert is shown to me
frm.Elements("password").Value = strOldPassword ' this line never executes
MsgBox ("password entered") ' this line never executes
```

The relevant HTML on the web page:

```
<input type="password" tabindex="1" class="input-xlarge" id="password" name="password"  autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: strOldPassword is just a string variable for the password I am trying to log in with. I will attempt this using the Document.GetElementsByName() method and update if it works.

Comment: Set an id and try with `getElementById`: http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_getref.asp

Comment: This WORKED! simple solutions are hard to come by. web.Document.getElementById("password").Value = strOldPassword

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I post my comment as answer in order you can check it as solution, learn about ["How does accepting an answer work?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy way is use [`getElementById` method](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_getref.asp):

```
web.Document.getElementById("password").Value = strOldPassword
```